# How should posix_spawn() behave when given a file with an unrecognized executable magic number?

Tags: posix, glibc, libc

The [glibc implementation](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/spawni.c;h=f19862ffff14a16d9513323fda1c7fd030f87213;hb=f574184a0e4b6ed69a5d9a3234543fba6d2a7367) of posix_spawn tries sending the file to /bin/sh if execve() fails with ENOEXEC:

```
__execve (file, argv, envp); 
if (errno == ENOEXEC)
  script_execute (file, argv, envp)
```

The [POSIX sample implementation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/xrat/xsh_chap03.html) simply fails if execve() fails in any way:

```
execve(path, argv, envp);
exit(127);              /* exec failed */
```

The [POSIX specification for posix_spawn()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) does not specify anything about how to handle files that would result in ENOEXEC if sent to execve(). As a possible contrast, the [POSIX specification for the exec* family of functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html) specifically states that execlp() and execvp() should invoke sh in the case of an unrecognized executable type:

> There are two distinct ways in which the contents of the process image
>   file may cause the execution to fail, distinguished by the setting of
>   errno to either [ENOEXEC] or [EINVAL] (see the ERRORS section). In the
>   cases where the other members of the exec family of functions would
>   fail and set errno to [ENOEXEC], the execlp() and execvp() functions
>   shall execute a command interpreter and the environment of the
>   executed command shall be as if the process invoked the sh utility
>   using execl() as follows:
>
> execl([shell path], arg0, file, arg1, ..., (char *)0);
>
> where [shell path] is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility, file
>   is the process image file, and for execvp(), where arg0, arg1, and so
>   on correspond to the values passed to execvp() in argv[0], argv[1],
>   and so on.

So, is the glibc implementation non-conforming? Or is the POSIX specification just a bit vague here? Isn't there a security risk in the glibc implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior might be acceptable (by analogy) for `posix_spawnp`, even if not officially sanctioned, but I think you're right that it's non-conformant, and moreover that it's dangerously non-conformant for plain `posix_spawn`. The shell invocation code should simply be removed.

Comment: Confirmed as a [bug](http://sources.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13134) and [fixed](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=d96de9634a334af16c0ac711074c15ac1762b23c) by upstream.